# Detect IDLE status of SPI protocol under STM32

Tags: stm32

I need to know the start and stop of SPI transmission under STM32 MCUs. In my project, I send 10bytes(array) and the receiver puts them into its array.

If the receiver joins with a delay, it might lose some packages and doesn't know when it starts and stops filling its array. So it is vital to detect the transmission status.

In my structure, I use software NSS (CS is not connected)

Comment: nss and cs are the same thing, slave select, chip select, etc...can use the one from the spi peripheral or make your own from a gpio.

Answer (score 2):

You need to introduce some kind of protocol, or at least framing detection. SPI is just a stream of bytes if there is nothing else being done.

1) First transfer some initialization data to know when slave is present and in sync. Then continue with your normal packets.

2) Put a delay between packets on TX end and and put a shorter timeout on RX end. This way the RX knows that it got an incomplete packet and will restart at first byte when TX sends next packet.

3) Frame the data with start of packed ID bytes and end of packet ID bytes. Maybe with a length as well. Then you can ignore any data until start ID is seen, and check if you get end ID after correct amount of data. Only problem is if your data bytes accidentally contains these IDs. This is where coding the data helps, for example send data as ASCII, using hexadecimal numbers and letters for data, and letters X and Y are free for packet start and stop delimiters.

4) Use the chip select to detect first and last bytes of SPI packet. As you have fixed length packet, just use falling edge to restart reception, or rising edge to latch in last 10 bytes, or use both edges. STM32 can generate an interrupt from the edges of CS pin.

Edit: after learning the CS pin is not connected, only way to get even the byte sync correct would be the use of timeouts and resetting the bit reception in the timeout as well.

Comment: it's worse than that. SPI is just a stream of bits

Comment: @Jasen not it is not. To the MCU it is a stream of bytes. And it will resyncronize the bit reception with hardware if CS is used. MCU won't give partial bytes, but a byte after 8 bits (or whataever the configured length is). But in this case, the CS is not used on the receiving MCU so it can't reset the bit counter and start syncronizing to first bit of a byte.

Comment: Yeah, that timing method can cure the stream of bits problem.

Comment: Thank you for your compelete answer.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't a specific signal to indicate a byte or packet boundary, you have two ways to deal with this:

- special sync pattern to figure out where the boundaries are
- idle pattern detection (kind of the same thing)

To make this work in a general case, you might have to re-code your data payload in a way that ensures that it cannot include these special patterns, by scrambling or some other method.

This gets especially difficult with SPI since the hardware is byte-oriented. So there will need to be an aligner layer on the receive side to deal with cases when the transmitter hasn’t sent a sequence on an 8-clock boundary.